# Need help with the powershell script

Tags: powershell

I need some help with a power shell script. That is 
using a power shell I need to activate all the features of all the site collections by  iterating each site collections in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

u can try

`Get-SPWebApplication xxx | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | % {Enable-SPFeature "xxx" -Url $_.Url}`